# Can MicrosoftGraph LicenseAssignments contain invalid SkuID

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We have written an application based on the Microsoft Graph .NET library that lists the license assignments for a tenant.
It basically iterates over the list of 'User' objects and inspects the 'assignedLicenses' property. The 'AssignedLicense' has a property 'skuId' that we use to query for more detailled information about the license itself.

Update:
We construct the id for the ['Get subscribedSku'](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/subscribedsku_get) call ourselves as follows: organizationId + '_' + assignedLicense.SkuId.

Now we have a customer, that seems to have users with license assignments, that have skuIDs that are "unknown" or "invalid" in regards, that they cannot be loaded using for example the ['Get subscribedSku'](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/subscribedsku_get) method. The error that is returned is

> Resource 'organizationId-SkuID' does not exist or one of its queried
>   reference-property objects are not present.

So my question is:
Is it possible/intended, that a LicenseAssignment can contain a SkuId, that cannot be loaded using the above mentioned (REST) method.

Answer (score 1):

The **id** used to query for the **Get subscribedSku** is not the **skuId** property. It should use the **id** instead of **skuId**. Please refer the response from **Get subscribedSku** and notice that there are two properties **skuId** and **id**:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: application/json

{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#subscribedSkus/$entity",
    "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
    "consumedUnits": 14,
    "id": "48a80680-7326-48cd-9935-b556b81d3a4e_c7df2760-2c81-4ef7-b578-5b5392b571df",
    "prepaidUnits": {
        "enabled": 25,
        "suspended": 0,
        "warning": 0
    },
    "servicePlans": [
        {
            "servicePlanId": "8c098270-9dd4-4350-9b30-ba4703f3b36b",
            "servicePlanName": "ADALLOM_S_O365",
            "provisioningStatus": "Success",
            "appliesTo": "User"
        },
        {
            "servicePlanId": "9f431833-0334-42de-a7dc-70aa40db46db",
            "servicePlanName": "LOCKBOX_ENTERPRISE",
            "provisioningStatus": "Success",
            "appliesTo": "User"
        }
    ],
    "skuId": "c7df2760-2c81-4ef7-b578-5b5392b571df",
    "skuPartNumber": "ENTERPRISEPREMIUM",
    "appliesTo": "User"
}
```

You can [list all the subscribedSkus](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/subscribedsku_list) and check whether the **skuId** in cotained in them. Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately the application builds the query id a bit different than I described (I will update my question after commenting). As it turns out, the AssignedLicence.SkuID contains a guid (as you described). The combined ID that is used to call the  'subscribedSku' api is constructied in our app by prefixing the id of the organization.

Comment: Based on the testing, it is not able to assign an invalidate licence. To narrow down this issue, I suggest that you check all the product licences assigned to the user using the [portal of Office 365](https://portal.office.com/adminportal/home)->Admin Center->Home->Edit a user->Product licences edit.

Comment: We extended our logging to figure out which of the (many) users is the one causing trouble. As soon as we have feedback from the customer, I'll add our findings here. Thanks again for taking the time.

Comment: It turned out, the user has 2 license assignments with the following Guids 94763226-9b3c-4e75-a931-5c89701abe66 and f73dabdf-ca08-41cb-b736-64280a003fe1. Loading the user in Powershell shows only one license (STANDARDWOFFPACK_FACULTY) which seems to be 94763226-9b3c-4e75-a931-5c89701abe66.

Comment: Same behavior in the management portal. The license with the Id f73dabdf-ca08-41cb-b736-64280a003fe1 doesn't show up there. So the question is... what is it and where could it come from?

Comment: Are you able to find this license using Azure AD Graph?

Comment: From what I can see from the logs, it is not returned when using the request described in https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/subscribedsku_list

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I mean is that whether the incorrect licence was listed using the [Azure AD Graph](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#GetAUser) instead of Microsoft Graph?

Comment: Since I have no direct access, I've requested this information from the customer and asked him to use "graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net". Is there an official documentation available for the SkuIDs (which ID is which product in human readable form)? Thanks again.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no such official document which maps all the available SkuIDs.

Comment: We have feedback from the customer. The GUID shows also up when queried via Azure AD Graph.  "skuId": "94763226-9b3c-4e75-a931-5c89701abe66" and "skuId": "f73dabdf-ca08-41cb-b736-64280a003fe1"

Comment: Any idea what "f73dabdf-ca08-41cb-b736-64280a003fe1" is and why it doesn't show up in the tenants licenses? As a workaround I currently ignore those licenses that cannot be found but it doesn't "feel" good.